# What does Instance() do in Python assignments?

Tags: python

var = Instance(object)?

Comment: Since it's not part of the standard library, we can only guess.  Where did you see this code?  Please provide a reference or a link to the place where you saw this code.

Comment: Perhaps s/he meant `isinstance`?

Comment: @elo80ka: Unlikely: the question's syntax isn't close to `isinstance` at all.

Answer (score 4):

It calls the `__call__()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I thought it was from the standard library. On inspection, it is from enthought.traits.api.Instance. It holds a reference to an object instance. If you pass a specific class to the constructor (e.g. Instance(MyClass) ), it does validation to make sure you pass the correct class.